# I can't use my windows key

Tags: windows

I haven't been able to use my windows key since the last update on my computer.

It works briefly on startup but shortly after applications boot up, it either stops working all together or isn't recognized at all..

Comment: Have you tried another (USB) keyboard?

Comment: Is that a laptop ?

Answer (score 0):

How many "Windows" (Start) keys does your keyboard have?

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.